# R: Fill in 0 in values that are above and below a benchmark

Tags: r, outliers

I'm currently writing my master thesis and when I made a regression I found out that I have some outliers which I would like to either delete or fill in a zero. I got a dataframe with company names and their daily returns from 2010 until 2021. [image]

The dataframe is called xsr. I want to find the outliers which are above 0.5 and below -0.5. I managed to create a dataframe according to this condition `xsr_short <- xsr[,c(2:214)] <0.5`. Then I tried to pick the false values `outliers <- subset(xsr_short, xsr_short = FALSE)`. Which just gives me back the initial `xsr_short`.

I also tried it with the `select` command: `xsr_short <- select(xsr, c('ABBN SW Equity':'ZWM SW Equity') < 0.5)`.
The output to this is:

```
    Error in `select()`:
! NA/NaN argument
Backtrace:
  1. dplyr::select(xsr, c("ABBN SW Equity":"ZWM SW Equity") < 0.5)
 22. base::.handleSimpleError(`<fn>`, "NA/NaN argument", base::quote("ABBN SW Equity":"ZWM SW Equity"))
 23. rlang (local) h(simpleError(msg, call))
 24. handlers[[1L]](cnd)
Warning messages:
1: In eval_tidy(expr, context_mask) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In eval_tidy(expr, context_mask) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

I need to fill in the second condition > -0.5 and then delete the values that are out of this range.

Thank you very much in advance for your help and your time!

Comment: Try with `==`, not `=`: `subset(xsr_short, xsr_short == FALSE)` or better yet, do not explicitly compare to TRUE/FALSE, they already are logical conditions, use `subset(xsr_short, !xsr_short)` instead.

Comment: It's usually considered bad practice to delete outliers unless you have reason to know that they are impossible values or that something went wrong with the measurement.  Every distribution is expected to get some values in the "tails", and these are valid data. Often the "outliers" are even the most interesting data to look at.  What combination of factors caused these to be very high or low?  What can we learn from that?

Comment: @RuiBarradas Are you sure your code works? `xsr_short` is defined as  `xsr[,c(2:214)] < 0.5` and hence a matrix, not a dataframe. `subset(xsr_short, !xsr_short)` should not work on a matrix.

Comment: @dww You are right but I saw daily returns of 6000% which is quite unusual for a listed company. Anyway I'm just figuring out why my regression shows strange results.

Comment: @DarrenTsai I doesn't work indeed.

Comment: In your case you should **not** use `subset` because `subset` is designed to extract a certain range of rows. The most basic way is `xsr[2:214][xsr[2:214] > 0.5] <- 0` and `xsr[2:214][xsr[2:214] < -0.5] <- 0`

Comment: @DarrenTsai I see the outliers now, thank you! Do you know how I can change their value inside the xsr matrix?

Comment: After running my code, all values above 0.5 and below -0.5 become 0 in `xsr`, right?

Comment: @DarrenTsai ah yeah I deleted the zero. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are less concerned with an actual subset but rather just switching out unwanted values in your data while preserving what you have for the regression. In that case, the `tidyverse` package may be helpful. First, you can load this package as well as this fake dataset:

```
#### Load Tidyverse ####
library(tidyverse)

#### Make Data Frame ####
data <- data.frame(IV = c("Control","Treatment",
                          "Control","Treatment"),
                   DV = c(-9999,2,4,5555))
data
```

Which gives you this:

```
         IV    DV
1   Control -9999
2 Treatment     2
3   Control     4
4 Treatment  5555
```

From there you can simply use `mutate` and `ifelse` to remove the unwanted values and replace then with NA missing values with this code, saving the data into a new version with the replacement values:

```
#### Swap Outliers with NA Values ####
clean.data <- data %>% 
  mutate(DV = ifelse(DV < 0,
                     NA,
                     ifelse(DV > 100,
                            NA,
                            DV)))
clean.data
```

Which gives you this:

```
       IV DV
1   Control NA
2 Treatment  2
3   Control  4
4 Treatment NA
```

As some others have noted, its generally bad practice to delete outliers in your data unless you have a defensible reason to do so. So if you do remove them, make sure you have something justifiable to include in your thesis that explains why you removed the values.

Comment: No prob! Please accept my answer if you found it useful :)